# ¿Cómo se extrae de un tipo de dato String tipos de datos enteros para sumarlos?

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, jpa, junit

Estoy realizando una aplicación de prestamos de libros en una biblioteca. 
Me han formulado el siguiente requerimiento: 
**No deben salir de la biblioteca aquellos libros donde los componentes numéricos de su ISBN (código identificador del libro) sumen más de 30**.
Ejemplo de **ISBN**: **A874B69Q**. 
Los componentes numéricos son **8,7,4,6 y 9**. Todos ellos suman **34**. Según el requerimiento ese libro no debe salir de la biblioteca, el usuario lo debe leer en las instalaciones de la misma.
¿Qué método o algoritmo me permite evaluar cada carácter del ISBN para extraer los componentes numéricos y realizar la suma? 
Estoy desarrollando el proyecto en Java EE. 
Espero grata ayuda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi amigo.... Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Me funcionó perfectamente...
Tenía algo parecido, fue de gran ayuda tú aporte... ¡te lo agradezco! Este era mi código.

La gran diferencia estaba en el for y el If

```
public static boolean DigitosNumericosIsbn (String IsbnLibro){
  System.out.println("Ingresé al método DigitosNumericosIsbn");    
  int sumaDigitosIsbn = 0;    
   char[] arreglo = IsbnLibro.toCharArray();
for (char caracter : arreglo){
    if ( Character.isDigit(caracter) ){
        System.out.println("Los dígitos son:"+caracter);
        sumaDigitosIsbn+=caracter;
        System.out.println("El resultado de DigitosIsbn es:"+sumaDigitosIsbn);
    }
}
if (sumaDigitosIsbn<30) {
                    System.out.println("prestar libro");
                    //return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("El libro será prestado por 15 días"); 
        }

return false;


}
```

Aunque me gustaría saber la estructura del if. ¿comparas los posibles números del ISBN del libro si son números naturales?  Es lo que entiendo.
Aún así... Muchas gracias por tú aporte.

Comment: Ahora lo que tengo que calcular es la fecha de devolución del libro. Al  ejecutar el préstamo no debe mostrar el mensaje "prestar libro por 15 días" si no que debo calcular la fecha de devolución a partir de la fecha de entrega. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Crea un vector en donde separes cada carácter y pongas ese carácter en una posición para luego recorrerlo e ir preguntando si es un número, de ser true la condición a una variable le vas sumando ese número, me explicaré con un código a manera de ejemplo; supongamos que el ISBN de un libro es el mismo que propusiste tu, A874B69Q.

Supongo que tienes tu código en una variable:

```
String ISBN = "A84B69Q";
```

Crearemos un Array:

```
char[] ary = ISBN.toCharArray();
```

Básicamente la línea de código anterior crea un array de carácteres en donde cada carácter de tu ISBN quedará en una posición de dicho array de esta forma

```
ary[0] = 'A';
ary[1] = '8';
ary[2] = '7';
```

Así sucesivamente hasta la última posición del array que será el último dígito de tu código

```
ary[7] = 'Q';
```

Ahora que tenemos nuestro array creado, vamos a inicializar en 0 una variable que se encargará de almacenar la suma de los número que encontremos en dicho array

```
int SumaDigitos = 0;
```

Ahora que tenemos nuestra variable SumaDigitos inicializada, recorreremos el array para encontrar qué caracteres son números y que otros son letras, para esto usaremos un ciclo for.

```
for(int i=0; i<ary.length; i++){
  if((ary[i] == '1') || (ary[i] == '2') || (ary[i] == '3') || (ary[i] == '4') || (ary[i] == '5') || (ary[i] == '6') || (ary[i] == '7') || (ary[i] == '8') || (ary[i] == '9')){
    SumaDigitos = SumaDigitos +  
      Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(ary[i]));
  }
}
```

Al final sólo haremos una validación, si nuestra variable SumaDigitos es mayor que 30 obtendrás un mensaje diciendo "El libro no puede salir de la biblioteca".

> **CÓDIGO COMPLETO**

```
import java.util.*;

public class codigoISBN
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String ISBN = "A84B69Q";
    char[] ary = ISBN.toCharArray();

    int SumaDigitos = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<ary.length; i++){
      if((ary[i] == '1') || (ary[i] == '2') || (ary[i] == '3') || (ary[i] == '4') || (ary[i] == '5') || (ary[i] == '6') || (ary[i] == '7') || (ary[i] == '8') || (ary[i] == '9')){
        SumaDigitos = SumaDigitos +  Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(ary[i]));
      }
    }
    if(SumaDigitos>30)
      System.out.println("Este libro no puede ser prestado");
    else{
      System.out.println("Este libro si puede ser prestado");
    }
  }
}
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, ¡no te desanimes!
Saludos.